# while loop not working Java

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop

When I create a variable and wrap the code in a while loop it never repeats. Here's a sample of code I tried it on.

```
String repeat = "y";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (repeat == "y"){
        String word1 = "this";
        String word2 = "that";
        String word3 = word1 + word2;
        System.out.println(word3);
        for(int x = 10; x<20; x = x+1){

            word3 = word1 + word3;
            System.out.println(word3);
        }
        repeat = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

No matter what the input is in the end of the script, it just ends. Any help?

Comment: Use `String`'s `equals` method to compare `String` values, not `==`, which compares object references to determine if they refer to the same object.

Comment: @rgettman They are literals here though, unless there's something missing in the code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, they are literals, so `"y"` will be interned.  The `while` loop will be entered for that reason.  But after `repeat = keyboard.nextLine();`, then `repeat` won't be a literal any more.  Either way, `.equals` is needed here.

Comment: @rgettman Right, it'll fail the next time. I stopped thinking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
 while (repeat == "y")
```

to

```
while("y".equalsIngnoreCase(repeat))
```

and

```
keyboard.nextLine() ;
```

to

```
keyboard.next();
```

Reading  [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) will be helpful.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I checked the javadoc, and Scanner does not have a `readLine()` method.

Comment: @Marcelo Yes .it has next() method to read line .I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare a string using '=='. you are comparing the object reference. You are essentially asking if the two objects are the same, rather than comparing the string contents. Try using the String.compareTo(..)  method.

Example:

```
while (repeat.compareTo("y") == 0) {
```

Comment: Why `compareTo` over `equals`?

Comment: There is no preference, other than that you could diverge extra information from the return value, otherwise equals works as well.

Comment: If you look at the source code of `equals` and `compareTo` you will see that `equals` is definitely faster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably comes from the facts you compare two objects with = but I guess what you want to do is compare Strings with the String method  equals, so it would look like that:

```
while(repeat.equals("y")){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `==` to compare strings.

Try this:-

```
  while ("y".equalsIngnoreCase(repeat) )
```